# Find the derivative of a multivariable Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution

The function is 
$$F(x)=\int_{1}^{4x}\cot(t)\,dt. $$

I begin by writing in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$ to make substitution easier.
$$F(x)=\int_{1}^{4x} \frac{\cos(t)}{\sin(t)}\,dt. $$
From here I picked my $u$ substitution 
\begin{align*}
u&=\sin(u)\\
du&=\cos(t)\,dt,
\end{align*}
which yielded 
$$\int_{1}^{4x} \frac{1}{u}\,du,$$
and thus I get 
$$\ln|\sin(t)|. $$
My answer should be $4\cot(4x)$ and I can't figure out how to get a $\cos$ from this or if I messed up earlier on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to use the first part of the FTC.

Note that $F=f\circ g$, where
$$f(x)=\int_1^x \cot(t)\,dt \qquad \text{and}\qquad g(x)=4x.$$
Then
$$f'(x)=\cot(x) \qquad \text{and}\qquad g'(x)=4.$$
Therefore, by the chain rule, the derivative of $F(x)$ is $f'(g(x))\,g'(x)$. That is,
$$F'(x)=\cot(4x)\cdot4.$$